# Merging 2 dictionaries by keys without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge, overwrite

Suppose I have 2 dictionaries:

```
ss = {'1':{'tier 1': {'valid_detailed': 66, 'valid_approx': 68, 'valid_unmapped': 56, 'valid_total': 288}}}
tt = {'1':{'tier 2': {'valid_detailed': 44, 'valid_approx': 33, 'valid_unmapped': 22, 'valid_total': 111}}}
```

I want to merge them together, but not overwrite the keys, only add things new items when the keys are different. Basically, I want to get this:

```
zz = {'1':{'tier 1': {'valid_detailed': 66, 'valid_approx': 68, 'valid_unmapped': 56, 'valid_total': 288}, 'tier 2': {'valid_detailed': 44, 'valid_approx': 33, 'valid_unmapped': 22, 'valid_total': 111}}}
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
result_dict = {}
  dicts = [ss, tt]
  for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
      result_dict.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

It almost works. I end up with this, which is not exactly what I want:

```
result_dict
>>>{'tier 1': ['valid_all_row', 'all_all_row', 'valid_all_row', 'all_all_row'],'tier 2': ['valid_all_row', 'all_all_row', 'valid_all_row', 'all_all_row']}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What code have you tried, and how does it come up short?

Comment: I added what I've tried so far. Just doing `z = {**ss, **tt}` obviously won't work either.

Comment: Your definitions of `ss`, `tt` and `zz` aren't valid Python.

Comment: I have fixed the `:` in the dictionaries to make it valid Python.

Comment: Suppose both `ss` and `tt` had a `tier 3` at the top level, with different values within.  What should end up in `zz`?

Comment: I suppose that should look like this: `zz = {'1':{'tier 3': {'valid_detailed': 66, 'valid_approx': 68, 'valid_unmapped': 56, 'valid_total': 288, ''valid_detailed': 44, 'valid_approx': 33, 'valid_unmapped': 22, 'valid_total': 111}}}`. I have simplified my question as I will actually  want something like: `{'1':{'tier 1':,..., 'tier 2': ...}, '2': {'tier 1':,..., 'tier 2': ...},...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ss = {'tier 1': {'valid_detailed': 66, 'valid_approx': 68, 'valid_unmapped': 56, 'valid_total': 288}}

tt = {'tier 2': {'valid_detailed': 44, 'valid_approx': 33, 'valid_unmapped': 22, 'valid_total': 111}}

zz={}
for i in ss.keys():
    zz[i]=ss[i]

for i in tt.keys():
    zz[i]=tt[i]
```

Result:

```
zz={'tier 1': {'valid_detailed': 66,
  'valid_approx': 68,
  'valid_unmapped': 56,
  'valid_total': 288},
 'tier 2': {'valid_detailed': 44,
  'valid_approx': 33,
  'valid_unmapped': 22,
  'valid_total': 111}}
```

Comment: You could replace the first loop with `zz = ss.copy()`.